# SSH Connection closed after issuing first command

Tags: perl, ssh, telnet, openssh

I am using Perl OpenSSH (Net::OpenSSH) to connect Cisco Devices.  I am able to connect the devices but the problem is, it is disconnecting after issuing my first command on the server.

Please check the code below for Connections and to capture Command output.

Connection code:

```
my %params = (
       host         => $hostname,
       user         => $username,
       passwd       => $password,          
       timeout      => defined $timeout ? $timeout : $self->{timeout},
       kill_ssh_on_timeout => 1,
       master_opts => [
           -o => "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
           -o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
           -o => "ServerAliveInterval=120",
       ]
   );  

   $ssh_connection_obj = Net::OpenSSH->new(%params);
```

To Capture Command:

Commands are :

1. sh int desc - I am getting output for this command, since this is my first command. After that i am getting the below error as mentioned.
2. sh arp - So this is my second one. Because the connection closed error after my first command output. I am getting nothing on this command.

But This is all happening with Perl OpenSSH module. but working good with Telnet module. And also if i try login manually using terminal window of my local machine, that time also working fine. So i am just thinking. Is that issue with OpenSSH module? or Cisco Devices?

Also If it is Juniper devices, the OpenSSH module responding pretty good on all commands.

```
@openssh_output = $ssh_connection_obj->capture("$cmd");
```

I am getting output for the first command. But I am getting this error

```
Connection to <IP_ADDRESS> closed by remote host.
```

when i try to capture output for another command.

Also i have tried with Telnet connection (new Net::Telnet). It is working good without any issues for all consequent commands.

Comment: [Net::Appliance::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Appliance::Session) is a good alternative for sake of Cisco

Comment: Can you add more code -- what is the `$cmd`, and in particular the one that fails? (It may well be about the command itself.) Perhaps that's why this is getting close votes.

Comment: @zdim. Thank you. I just updated my question with Commands.

Comment: Is the connection getting closed immediately, or does it seem to be a timeout?

Comment: Yes. It is getting closed immediately after the output of first command. Something weird. I have tested with nearly 100 Cisco devices to make sure it is not issue related to devices.

Comment: Re: "_closed immediately after the output of first command._" -- is it closed _after the first command_ (before the second one is even attempted) as the comment above says, or _as it runs the second command_ as the question implies?  I don't know about Cisco things but this is debugging.  You can find out by adding print statements right before and right after you run the second command, having `$| = 1` set (no buffering), and redirecting STDERR along with STDOUT to a file. Then you should see when exactly the error message comes.

Comment: See the module FAQ: [Connecting to switches, routers, etc.](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Connecting-to-switches,-routers,-etc.)

Comment: term len issue?  Or not reading output